# Uploading to an FTP server on the same wifi network (python)

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to upload a file to an ftp server on my same wifi network to get a picture on to a digital picture frame. I succeeded in uploading through file explorer, but when uploading using a python script I get a 530 response.

Here is the code so far

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP()
ftp.connect("111.111.1.11", 1111)  #dummy host and port
file = open('C:/path/to/file/test1.png','rb')                  
ftp.storbinary('test.png', file)     
file.close()                                    
ftp.quit()
```

The server does not requre me to log in with a username and password on file explorer, is there some sort of default I need?

Comment: Have you tried adding `ftp.login()` after establishing the connection? It uses the `anonymous` user, maybe that user is required...
Checkout the example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`530` error code means `Authentication failed error` so you are missing the authentication piece. Maybe you can do something like this:

```py
  ftp = FTP(source_address=("111.111.1.11", 1111))
  ftp.login(user, password)
```

Note that if you don't provide a user and password it will login with:
user     anonymous
password anonymous
as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#module-ftplib)

Also I would recommend you reading about S-FTP (Secure FTP) because in FTP the credentials are passed in clear text in the login request.
S-FTP is a communication protocol similar to FTP but built on top of ssh.

Hope this helped you !

Comment: That works! I didn't realise it could be done anonymously